# Cant Get OnCollisionEnter and GetKey to know im pressing the key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

When I try to if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) inside of the OnCollisionEnter function it compleatly ignores the if input part compleatly and doenst run or do anything with it

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Trigger"))
    {
        canvas.enabled = true; this happens

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("RVinterior"); this doesnt happen
            Debug.Log("E Pressed"); this doent happen
        }
    }
}
```

I tried making it to where as im colliding and if i press e then it would load the scene called RVinterior.

Comment: Have you tried to check that Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) actually evaluates to true when you expect it to? The behaviour would be completely explained if it was false. From your snippet it does also seem like you might want to be using GetButtonDown instead (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html), as in doing a singular action. I would probably elevate the check to keypress to be at the same level as where you determine that some collission has happened. I don't really dabble in Unity, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`OnTriggerEnter` only execute once until you complete leave the counter object and re-encounter again. After the collision is triggered, `OnTriggerStay` will be kept invoke until they don't collide any more. You can implement your trigger function in `OnTriggerEnter` and other detecting implementation in `OnTriggerStay`:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Trigger"))
    {
        canvas.enabled = true;
    }
}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Trigger"))
    {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            // you should only load scene one time,
            // you can remove the collider component here
            // or use flags to control the execution
            SceneManager.LoadScene("RVinterior"); 
            Debug.Log("E Pressed"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very unlikely that you press E in the same frame you enter your trigger, rather use [OnTriggerStay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html). [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) is only called once, the frame your collider enters the Trigger area. OnTriggerStay is called every frame the player is inside the trigger.

As RoyM mentioned you should also rather use GetButtonDown/GetKeyDown since you don't want it to be triggered multiple times.

So the code would look something like this:

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Trigger"))
    {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            canvas.enabled = true; // you probably want this only be done once 
            SceneManager.LoadScene("RVinterior");
            Debug.Log("E Pressed"); 
        }
    }
}
```